# What does the unsigned keyword do here?

Tags: c++

I wrote some C++ code to show ASCII characters on a console which I found in a book i was reading. The code looked like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()  
{  
    for (unsigned char i = 32; i<128; i++)  
       cout << i;  
    int response;  
    cin >> response;  
    return 0;  
}
```

When I take away the `unsigned` keyword and use `signed` instead, the results become infinite and the PC beeps until I shut off the executable file. But when I use an `int i` variable instead I don't need to unsign the variable. Why is that?

Comment: If you can put a parameter near that beeping char value, you can play music.

Comment: Very simply, a `char` is (in most versions of C) 8 bits.  A signed `char` has a range from -128 to 127.  An unsigned `char` has a range between 0 and 255.  When an integer numeric variable (which `char` is) is incremented past it's upper bound it "wraps" around to the lower bound.  So signed `char` will never be equal to or greater than 128.

Comment: Putting space inside the angle brackets of `#include < iostream >` relies on an extension to the standard, of questionable validity. Don't do that.

Comment: @HotLicks: I'm not sure about C++, but in C, signed integer types don't "wrap" around, they overflow, and cause undefined behaviour. Also, again I'm not sure about C++, but in C, `char` can be either signed or unsigned by default, it is implementation-defined, so `char` may be able to hold values over 127.

Comment: 127 is 0111 1111 in both signed and unsigned. Add 1 and it becomes 1000 0000. Now for (signed) char this is -127, but in unsigned char it is 128.

Comment: @ManojR: That is true for two's complement, but the C standard doesn't specify whether integer types are represented as two's complement. The C standard also states that signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour. As I've mentioned in other comments, a compiler is allowed to assume that integer arithmetic won't overflow (because if it did, the resulting behaviour would be undefined), as a result, GCC optimises based on this assumption.

Comment: @dreamlax - The "undefined behavior" is inevitably to "wrap" -- changing this behavior would no doubt break thousands (if not millions) of programs.  And you're right that the folks who defined C could never make up their minds whether `char` should be signed or unsigned by default (which is why I specifically said "signed char" and "unsigned char").

Comment: Just to add two cents: `gcc -Wall -Wextra` warns about infinite loop in case you don't use `unsigned`

Comment: @HotLicks: Both GCC and Clang assume that signed integer arithmetic won't overflow and optimise based on this assumption. This has been commented on some of the answers below.

Comment: @dreamlax -- What you mean is that those compilers ignore the possibility that overflow might occur in the process of doing their manipulations.  However, they likely *depend* on wrapping behavior in their optimizations, since it allows them to, in, say, an array index calculation, subtract a synthetic 4 from a value and then later add it back in with impunity.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`unsigned` simply means that the number won't become negative. Yeah, number, because a `char` really is just an 8-bit integer.

So when `unsigned`, every bit is used in the non-negative range, which will go from 0 to 255. When you leave out and use a `signed` (default) char, the range will go from -128 to 127, thus it will always be less than 128 and go into an infinite loop.

The beep you hear is due to the char of value 7 being "printed".

---

An `int`, on the other hand, even when signed goes all the way from -2.147... billions to +2.147 billions, so it will iterate normally until reaching 128 and stopping.

Comment: I just want to add that, when in doubt use an `int`. In C the `unsigned` values have some very counterintuitive integer promotion rules applied to them, which can bite you quite badly.

Comment: Actually it is implementation-defined whether a `char` is `signed` or `unsigned` by default.

Comment: @datenwolf - or, depending on your application, use unsigned for everything.  If you're using chars for low-level processing, sticking to `uintX_t` for everything can make life a lot easier

Comment: You can't assume a `char` is 8 bits (it's `CHAR_BIT` bits) or that `int` is 32 bits. `int` is at least 16.

Comment: @chris: You *can* assume it, but you shouldn't. (Actually POSIX guarantees `CHAR_BIT==8` and `int` is at least 32 bits, but the C standard only guarantees `CHAR_BIT >= 8` and `int` is at least 16 bits.)

Comment: @KeithThompson, Yeah the standard differs from what is actually out there in more than a few areas now.

Comment: @chris: For conforming implementations, it doesn't. An implementation with `CHAR_BIT==8` can certainly be conforming.

Comment: @KeithThompson, Yes, I meant differs as in reality is more specialized.

Comment: @chris: There are real-world implementations with `CHAR_BIT > 8` and with 16-bit `int` (probably mostly embedded).

Comment: @KeithThompson, I agree, there will always be environments like that, and the standard must support them now if it did when they were more common, but the majority of people don't find themself in that situation. I'm actually not exactly sure where this is going any more, to be honest. Now I'm inadvertently practically arguing for assuming something about them just from remarks.

Comment: An `int` is only required to be able to represent values in the range [-32767, 32767]. On most architectures today it has a larger range, but if you want to talk about that range you need to look at the values of `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` (from `<limits.h>` or `<climits>`, or `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` and `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` (from `<limits>`).

Comment: @chris "but the majority of people don't find themself in that situation" that was also true for 64bit pointers for a long time - which lead to programs that break when compiled for current CPUs and custom binary serialisation which is incompatible between 32bit and 64bit systems.

Answer (score 8):

The signed `char` type ranges from `-128` through `+127`.

Therefore, `i<128` can never be false, so your loop will never terminate.

Instead, `127 + 1` as a signed char will wrap around to `-128` (because it will set the sign bit), which will then continue through the loop a second time.

This second iteration will include *every* character, including `\a` (bell), which beeps when printed.

Comment: It's not guaranteed that signed integers will "wrap". It is in fact undefined behaviour, and [GCC is known to optimise on the assumption that signed integer arithemtic won't overflow](http://thiemonagel.de/2010/01/signed-integer-overflow/).

Comment: [Clang does the same kind of optimizations.](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html#signed_overflow)

Comment: *because it will set the sign bit* is a bit of an over-simplification, you might want to mention Two's complement here.

Answer (score 5):

Unsigned means that the variable will only contain positive values, which means that they have can contain larger positive numbers. The range of unsigned char is typically 0 to 255, and the range of a signed char is -128 to +127. This can vary on different hardware (but won't on most hardware you are likely to come across).

When a variable is incremented from it's maximum value, it overflows. What happens to the variable depends on whether it is unsigned or not. Unsigned types are guaranteed to become 0, while signed types the behaviour is undefined. On most systems that I've seen the variable wraps around to the minimum value (in this case -128), but you can't rely on this behaviour.

What this means is that the variable will never reach 128, so the loop will continue forever.

If you goto this page and look at fundamental data types you can see the typical ranges of signed vs unsigned of all fundamental types: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/

Comment: Signed integers don't necessarily wrap, there's no guarantee of that. Only unsigned integers are guaranteed to "wrap". In the C standard, signed integer overflow has undefined behaviour. GCC is known to optimise based on the assumption that signed integer types won't overflow.

Comment: Thanks @dreamlax, another corner of C++ that I didn't know existed. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`signed char` range is from -128 to +127, so it will always be less than 128

When you do

```
signed i=127;
i++;
```

`i` will usually be -128 (but you can't count with this behaviour)

`unsigned char` range is from 0 to 255

Not all [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) characters are printable! It is nonsense to print them.

Comment: Signed overflow is undefined behaviour, it just *usually* wraps.

Answer (score 3):

The types `signed char` and `unsigned char` are distinct integer types. As the names imply, one is a signed type (i.e., can represent negative values) and the other is an unsigned type (i.e., .can represent only non-negative values).

The type `char`, with no `signed` or `unsigned` prefix, is yet another distinct type. It has the same representation and range as *either* `signed char` *or* `unsigned char`; which one it is is implementation-defined. (A subtle point: they're still three distinct types even though two of them have identical characteristics.)

For typical implementations, all three of these types are 8 bits, and signed types are represented using two's-complement, giving `signed char` a range of -128 .. +127 and `unsigned char` a range of 0 .. +255.

On your implementation, it seems that plain `char` is signed (that's very common). So if `i` is of type `char`, then `i < 128` is *always* true, and you have an infinite loop. And incrementing a `char` or `signed char` object past its maximum value actually has undefined behavior, but typically it wraps around from the maximum value to the minimum value, which is what you're seeing. (The beep is probably produced when the character being printed is `\007`, the ASCII `BEL` character; either that, or you're sending control characters that mess up your terminal.)

Making `i` an `unsigned char` gives it a range from 0 to 255, and your loop stops when it reaches 128. (Incrementing a value of an unsigned type past its maximum value is well defined, but you don't do that anyway.)

`int` is always a signed type, and its range is required by the language to be at least -32767 .. +32767. These days, it's commonly 32 bits, with a range of -2147483648 .. +2147483647. But even with the minimum required range, it's more than big enough for your loop.

Answer (score 1):

A signed char (at least in a typcical case) can only represent values from -128 to +127. Since it can never have the value 128, your loop runs forever.

Officially, when it has the value 127 and you increment, the result is undefined behavior. In reality, on almost any typical machine (anything using 2's complement) when it has the value 127 and you increment, it'll wrap around to -128, increment back up to 127, wrap around to -128 and go through the whole cycle again.

With an unsigned char, you get values from 0 to (at least) 255, so when you get to 127 and increment, the value goes to 128, ending the loop as expected.

Likewise, an `int` is required to have a range from at least -32767 to +32767. Therefore, when it has a value of 127, and you increment, the result will be 128, as you'd normally expect.

Comment: [GCC optimises on the assumption that signed integers won't overflow](http://thiemonagel.de/2010/01/signed-integer-overflow/), so although there may be no architectural restriction on wrapping a signed int, it's still not safe to do so.